# Joomla Search Results ItemId

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

How to add the Itemid of each of the search results in Joomla.

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=74&virtuemart_category_id=6&lang=en
```

In above link &Itemid=521 is missing thats why not showing the correct page

Comment: Is the above link from a menu item?

Comment: A search result link with no Itemid,i want to add a itemid in above link

Comment: Are you trying to make a Menu item to go to these results?

Comment: I already have a menu item,ijust want to attach the itemid to each of the results

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really control Joomla URLs with out hacking/overriding code or using a third-party re-write tool like sh404sef or the Core Joomla Redirect component (J2.5+), is to make Menu items that are of the "External Url" type. Then define what ever URL you want:

> index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=74&virtuemart_category_id=6&lang=en&Itemid=521

*NOTE! I added **&Itemid=521** to the URL, but without setting a proper Menu item, you may experience unexpected module positioning...

Comment: Sorry but you are not getting,i created a custom joomla template,&Itemid=521 need to be added to display correct output in search results page otherwise it is displaying a blank page

Comment: Well, I think it get it. I have made  few Joomla sites and in Virtuemart, as well as Joomla itself, if you are linking to search results, you are not making Joomla urls correctly. You do not add itemids to urls to get templates to show or modules to show, you do that through the menu system and the Template administration.

Here is a link my Joomla Forum profile. You may want to post there, as the Joomla forums are very helpful!

http://forum.joomla.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=198283